# How to text at bottom of title page

Tags: titles

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document} \begin{titlepage}
\title{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA} \author{CCCCC
\\ University of sdfsdfsdf} \date{December 1, 2016}
\null \vfill \centering{BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB}
\maketitle \end{titlepage}
\section*{Preface}
\end{document}
```

For some reason, BBBBBBBBBBBBBB is at the bottom of the first page of the document. And AAAAAAAAAAA is on the title page (labelled as Page 2).

Can someone please suggest to me how I should fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You might take away the `\vfill` and `AAAAAAAAAA` being on the title page is as expected since by using `\title` you are asking LaTeX to put it on the title page.

Comment: The `titlepage` environment and `\maketitle` are different things. With this code you have a first title page with  just `BBBBBB…` at the bottom,  and a second title page, made by `\maketitle`. Further, `\title`, `\author`, ` \date` should be in the preamble. What you need is the `titling` package, which lets you customise the result of the `\maketitle``  command.

Comment: @Bernard And also provides a `titlingpage` which is something in-between ;).

Comment: I would do the titlepage completely from scratch. Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280

Answer (score 3):

Sort answer: Move `\maketitle` and place it just between  `\date` and `\null`

Additional notes:

- Now you can remove `\null`.
- Rememeber that any text before `\maketitle` will be placed in a previous page. It  must be the very first thing to print, except if you want a kind of cover page.
- You do not need the `titlepage` environment for this.
- On the other hand, `\centering` have not arguments. If you want limit the scope of `\centering`, use `{\centering ...}` ending `...` with a blank line or `\par`, but not `\centering{...}`.
- Finally, `\title`, `\author` and `\data` do no print anything, so they could be better in the preamble, but also are OK after the preamble (or even before of the preamble),  but obviously should be always before `\maketitle`.

In summary, your MWE could be changed to:

```
\documentclass{article} 
   \title{AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA} 
   \author{CCCCC\\ University of sdfsdfsdf} 
   \date{December 1, 2016}
\begin{document} 
   \maketitle
   \vfill 
   {\centering BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB\par}
   \newpage
   \section*{Preface}
\end{document}
```